# Dynamically created PictureBox Does not Show up in C#

Tags: c#

I was trying to Load a pictureBox in run time. There is no run time error. But the PictureBox does not show up.

Later on I also added InitializeComponent(), but it did not help.

My Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox picLoadingNew = new PictureBox();
            picLoadingNew.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            picLoadingNew.Image = global::QuiDip.Properties.Resources.ajax_loader_Long;
            picLoadingNew.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(790, 760);
            picLoadingNew.Name = "picLoadingNew";
            picLoadingNew.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(142, 22);
            picLoadingNew.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            //InitializeComponent();
            this.Controls.Add(picLoadingNew);
            picLoadingNew.Show();
            picLoadingNew.Visible = true;
        }
```

Comment: Try adding picLoadingNew.Refresh(); and this.Refresh(); end of the button click method. Or you can try picLoadingNew.Update();. If these don't work check for your image you are trying to show in picture box.

Comment: Setting the Size and Location but then using DockStyle.Fill is not very sensible.  It is at least going to be overlapped by button1, perhaps more.  Some odds you'll see it if you add picLoadingNew.BringToFront().  Make it better, add it with the designer and set its Visible property to False.  So all you have to do to see it is to set it to *true*.

Answer (score 1):

You wont need .Show or .Visible lines as this would be the default anyway, but you do certainly need the this.Controls.Add(picLoadingNew) - as long as the form is going to be the parent and not a Panel or anything else. If the PictureBox is sitting on top of another control like a panel, you actually need: panel.Controls.Add(picLoadingNew) - and not your current this.Controls.Add(picLoadingNew) line.

What I would try first as I can't see anything too wrong with your code is, change the default location of your picture box to:

picLoadingNew.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 5);

And remove the .Dock line.

This might be setting the PictureBox off screen (depending on the form's size?) - you haven't provided this so guessing what could be wrong. If the PictureBox is off screen, the new coordinates will force it to be top-left - so you should definitely see it then. Once you know it's working, you can then move it into position and set anchors later once you've proved the code is actually working.

You might find setting .SizeMode = StretchImage might be useful incase you're image is too large and again is "off screen". StretchImage will force the image to resize to fit nicely inside your PictureBox with the current .Size dimensions that you provided.

Something like:

```
PictureBox picLoadingNew = new PictureBox();
picLoadingNew.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
picLoadingNew.Image = global::QuiDip.Properties.Resources.ajax_loader_Long;
picLoadingNew.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 5);
picLoadingNew.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(142, 50);
picLoadingNew.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
parent.Controls.Add(picLoadingNew);
```

The code above worked for me (using my own image of course!).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work but there is a little problem. If your image is exactly positioned at the same location of another image and its size is identical, you can't see it. It is located behind the current image on screen.

Remove the Show and Visible call but add a call to BringToFront

```
this.Controls.Add(picLoadingNew);
// picLoadingNew.Show();
// picLoadingNew.Visible = true;
picLoadingNew.BringToFront();
```

By the way, what is the point in giving a specific size to your new image if then you ask it to Fill the available space on its container?

Comment: Care to comment the downvote? I would be really interested to know if there is something wrong in the answer.